# Where can I find extensions for RISUS?

Tags: risus

RISUS is an RPG system in 4 pages, completely setting-neutral and generally a good beer-and-pretzels game. However, I want to use it for more fleshed-out games. The core engine is good but I'd like to add, for example, loot.

It's very likely someone else has already made something like this (and tested it). There's the [RISUS Companion](http://shadowi01.free.fr/jdr/risus/The%20Risus%20Companion.pdf), but there's still gaps left and I'm looking for homebrew rules to cover them.

Is there an online forum/database/link collection (or something similar) of RISUS-related homebrew and houserules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out [Risusiverse](http://www.risusiverse.com/home), the official Risus wiki. They've got all sorts of optional rules there.